# How to run a script every time user inputs something?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<form>
<h4>ENTER NUMBER OF WORKMEN: <input type="number" id="s" oninput="helma.value=s.value; mha.value=s.value; sha.value=s.value;" ></h4><hr>
<h2>AVAILABILITY OF PPE</h2><hr>
HELMET&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="number" id="helma" >
Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="helmb" oninput="helmx.value=(parseInt(helmb.value)/parseInt(helma.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="helmx" for="helma helmb"></output>%<br><br>
SAFETY BELT&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="belta" value="">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="beltb" value="" oninput="beltx.value=(parseInt(beltb.value)/parseInt(belta.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="beltx" for="belta beltb"></output>%<br><br>
FR GLOVES&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="fra" value="3">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="frb" value="" oninput="frx.value=(parseInt(frb.value)/parseInt(fra.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="frx" for="fra frb"></output>%<br><br>
MATERIAL HANDLING GLOVES&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="mha">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="mhb" value="" oninput="mhx.value=(parseInt(mhb.value)/parseInt(mha.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="mhx" for="mha mhb"></output>%<br><br>
CUT RESISTANT GLOVES&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="cuta" value="4">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="cutb" value="" oninput="cutx.value=(parseInt(cutb.value)/parseInt(cuta.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="cutx" for="cuta cutb"></output>%<br><br>
EYE GUARD&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="eyea" value="2">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="eyeb" oninput="eyex.value=(parseInt(eyeb.value)/parseInt(eyea.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="eyex" for="eyea eyeb"></output>%<br><br>
NOSE MASK&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="masa" value="4">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="masb" oninput="masx.value=(parseInt(masb.value)/parseInt(masa.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="masx" for="masa masb"></output>%<br><br>
EAR PLUG (for Vibrator operation)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="eara" value="">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="earb" oninput="earx.value=(parseInt(earb.value)/parseInt(eara.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="earx" for="eara earb"></output>%<br><br>
SAFETY SHOE&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="sha">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="shb" oninput="shx.value=(parseInt(shb.value)/parseInt(sha.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="shx" for="sha shb"></output>%<br><br>
GUM BOOT&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="gba" value="4">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="gbb" oninput="gbx.value=(parseInt(gbb.value)/parseInt(gba.value))*100">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="gbx" for="gba gbb"></output>%<br><br>
LUMINOUS JACKET (FOR C-SET ONLY)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="lja">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="ljb" oninput="ljx.value=(parseInt(ljb.value)/parseInt(lja.value))*100;">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output name="ljx" for="lja ljb"></output>%<br><br>
<p id="avppesc"></p>
<script> //calculation of marks
 var average=0,flag=0;
 if (document.getElementById("helmx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("helmx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("beltx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("beltx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("frx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("frx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("mhx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("mhx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("cutx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("cutx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("eyex").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("eyex").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("masx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("masx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("earx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("earx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("shx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("shx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("gbx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("gbx").value; flag++; }
 if (document.getElementById("ljx").value>-1){ average=average+document.getElementById("ljx").value; flag++; }
 average=average/flag;
 document.getElementById("avppesc").innerHTML=average;

 </script>

<br><br><br>

 </form>
```

I want to run the script commented as 'calculation of marks' every time the user inputs something in the html form. If the user inputs nothing in the field, that should not be considered in the calculation.

I have been trying to use the `onload` function, nothing is working.

I expect the attribute with `id=avppesc` to show the value of average calculated in the script. Script should update anytime an user inputs something.

Comment: your code snippet is unreadable. Please try to simplify your code.

Comment: Please check [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oninput` event listener executes every time when value of `input` changes.
Let see if this is what you want.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form input');

let avppesc = document.querySelector('#avppesc');
for(let i = 0; i<inputs.length; ++i){
  inputs[i].addEventListener('input', onInputFunction);
}
  
function onInputFunction(){
  let average=0,flag=0;  
  for(let i = 1; i<inputs.length; ++i){  
    let id = inputs[i].id.slice(0,-1);
    let value = parseFloat(inputs[i].value) || 0;
    let ina = parseInt(document.querySelector('#'+id+'a').value);
    let inb = parseInt(document.querySelector('#'+id+'b').value);

    if(inb > 0 && ina>0)
    document.querySelector('#'+id+'x').value = inb/ina*100;
    
    if(value <= -1) continue;
    flag++;
    average += value;
  }
  
  average /= flag;
  
  avppesc.textContent = average;
}

//helmx.value=(parseInt(helmb.value)/parseInt(helma.value))*100
```

```html
<form>
<h4>ENTER NUMBER OF WORKMEN: <input type="number" id="s" oninput="helma.value=s.value; mha.value=s.value; sha.value=s.value;" ></h4><hr>
<h2>AVAILABILITY OF PPE</h2><hr>
HELMET&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="number" id="helma" >
Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="helmb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="helmx" for="helma helmb"></output>%<br><br>
SAFETY BELT&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="belta" value="">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="beltb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="beltx" for="belta beltb"></output>%<br><br>
FR GLOVES&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="fra" value="3">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="frb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="frx" for="fra frb"></output>%<br><br>
MATERIAL HANDLING GLOVES&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="mha">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="mhb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="mhx" for="mha mhb"></output>%<br><br>
CUT RESISTANT GLOVES&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="cuta" value="4">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="cutb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="cutx" for="cuta cutb"></output>%<br><br>
EYE GUARD&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Required&nbsp<input type="number" id="eyea" value="2">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="eyeb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="eyex" for="eyea eyeb"></output>%<br><br>
NOSE MASK&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="masa" value="4">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="masb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="masx" for="masa masb"></output>%<br><br>
EAR PLUG (for Vibrator operation)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="eara" value="">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="earb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="earx" for="eara earb"></output>%<br><br>
SAFETY SHOE&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="sha">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="shb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output id="shx" for="sha shb"></output>%<br><br>
GUM BOOT&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="gba" value="4">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="gbb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="gbx" for="gba gbb"></output>%<br><br>
LUMINOUS JACKET (FOR C-SET ONLY)&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<input type="number" id="lja">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp Available&nbsp<input type="number" id="ljb">&nbsp&nbsp MARKS: <output class='out' id="ljx" for="lja ljb"></output>%<br><br>
<p id="avppesc"></p>
</form>
```